# App Engine php facebook login with curl

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I have spent the last 2 full days attempting to add facebook login to my site with Goggle app engine, I saw in the documentation that curl would need to be enabled and can be done using a php.ini file, however despite following instructions I still cannot get a facebook session to set so that I can log the user in after the redirect, below is my code any help will go a long way thanks.

app.yaml

```
application: appname
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1


handlers: 
- url: /images
  static_dir: images  

- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets

- url: /includes
  static_dir: includes

- url: /http/.*
  script: http.php

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

php.ini

```
extension = "curl.so"
```

index.php

```
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php');
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/GraphUser.php');
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php');
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once ('/includes/php_functions/lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

/* USE NAMESPACES */

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;

/*PROCESS*/


if (!isset($_COOKIE['logged_in'])) {

$loginUrl = "";

$app_id = 'APP_ID';
$app_secret = 'APP_SECRET';
$redirect_url = 'http://localhost:9080/';

try {       

    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
    $sess = $helper -> getSessionFromRedirect();

    //this if block never happens because session will not set after redirect :/
    if (isset($sess)) {

        //create request object,execute and capture response
        $request = new FacebookRequest($sess, 'GET', '/me');
        // from response get graph object
        $response = $request -> execute();
        $graph = $response -> getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());
        // use graph object methods to get user details
        $name = $graph -> getName();
        $social_user_id = $graph -> getId();
        $profile_photo_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $social_user_id . '/picture?width=300';
        $email = $graph -> getProperty('email');

        $token = $sess -> getToken();


        //set cookies

        setcookie("logged_in", true, time() + 86400, "/");

        header("Location: http://localhost:9080/");
        exit();

    } else {

        $loginUrl = $helper -> getLoginUrl(array('email'));

    }

} catch (Exception $e) {



}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how yo expect this redirect to work - you do not have an entry in your app.yaml for login.php and you're redirecting to '/' which will invoke index.php.

Comment: I made an edit to this page, I accidentally wrote login.php but it should be index.php, the login page is rendered using index.php and redirects to the same page, if the facebook session is set it should then log the user in. Now very important to note I am using the newest development environment, I cant deploy my application live right now, so that being said is the issue with the development environment? because it seems your code is working in the live publish